# Need to start process which needs admin rights from Java code and get back errorlevel

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I have exe file which needs admin right to be run. I am using ProcessBuilder this way:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "/wait", "myexe.exe", "&", "echo", "%errorlevel%");
Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

As part of ProcessBuilder constructor parameters there has to be `cmd.exe /C` because without it it is impossible to starts myexe.exe - I always get error message

> The requested operation requires elevation.

With `cmd.exe /C` it is started normally and UAC asked me if I am sure to start it. But then I got to

```
java %errorlevel% from cmd.exe (process.exitValue())
```

which is always 0 and not %errorlevel% from myexe.exe.

Then I try to concatenate commands by `& end echo %errorlevel%`. Then I open input stream and read what was written by echo. It always read 0.

It works in batch file:

```
myexe.exe
echo %errorlevel&
```

But not inline as for ProcessBuilder. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the "errorlevel" (really the process exit value), you can use something like

```
Process p = processBuilder.start();
int errorLevel = p.waitFor();
```

The [`Process.waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) Javadoc says (in part),

> **Returns:**
>
> the exit value of the subprocess represented by this `Process` object. By convention, the value `0` indicates normal termination.

Comment: It does not work. waitFor() return 0, but if I run myexe.exe from cmd line and then echo %errorlevel% I got 544.

Comment: @bizdej Then I think you're out of luck. The above is how you get the "errorlevel" from a Java sub-process.

Comment: Yeah, but my.exe in that case is java subsubsubprocess ;). cmd.exe is subprocess. That is the problem. May be I need to prepare batch file which store %errorlevel% into file and my java application will read it, but this is so dirty solution!